# java - initiate VoIP calls through any VoIP Service Provider

Tags: java, voip

I work for a software company and we are currently looking for a cheap way for our customers to initiate phone calls through our software. We were thinking it would be nice if we could some how initiate the calls through the VoIP service provider that they already have. VoIP service providers like Skype and 8x8 seem to have individual APIs for placing calls through their service, but we were hoping there was a more generic/standard way to initiate calls from a VoIP service so we don't have to write an implementation for each VoIP service provider we want to support.

Our software is a java based application, so a java compatible solution would be appreciated. I have read that a PBX server like Asterisk might be a good solution to our issue, but we would prefer not to have our customers go through the additional step of installing a PBX server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol)

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Thanks for the quick response, but I am looking for a programmable solution to my problem. I will try out Server Fault though.

Comment: @MarcB I came across SIP while doing some research. I've read that it can be used to make VoIP soft phones, which is kind of what I'm trying to do. Do you know if it can be used to initiate calls through **any** VoIP service provider though and do you know of any good resources or sample code I could take a look at. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to talk about 2 separate software here:

- VoIP server: you need a server for VoIP to handle the calls from your users. (You will auto create user accounts for this from your java code if necessary). I don't think that it is important for this to be Java based so you can use any of the popular servers such as [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) or [Freeswitch](https://freeswitch.org/). If somehow you need this also to be Java based then maybe check [Brekeke](http://www.brekeke.com/sip/). From the server you can easily send out the calls to any VoIP provider or carrier (search for "SIP call termination" or "VoIP trunk providers")
- VoIP client: for this I can recommend the compact [java voip](https://www.mizu-voip.com/Software/Softphones/JVoIP.aspx) library from mizutech or the more complex [jitsi](https://jitsi.org/). You will need to integrate one of these with your java software.

Comment: Thanks Istvan. Mizutech and Jitsi seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.